# Need a script to import Rotoscoping mask

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-scripting

I am looking to perform rotoscoping on one of my videos.
I have found [Clearvid.io](http://clearvid.io/) online service that performs rotoscoping. They provide the points of the resultant masks of rotoscoping in a text file that can be imported into after effects.

Ask:
I need some help in writing a script that imports these points into Adobe after effects.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please find the input video file and the file containing the masks [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4ljtwdn8dnskt6/clearvid_7xfdjfbrjdt.zip).

Thank you.

Comment: from the text file: 

The format of the file is as follows:
- Frame number
  format - 'frame: ..'
- Number of points for the mask in this frame
  format - 'points: ..'
- Set of points specified as a series of concatenated x, y co-ordinates
  format - 'x1, y1, x2, y2, ...'

Comment: This question is a little broad. Can you specify what problem you're having?

Comment: Can I just say that the results look pretty bad. You would get better results using AE's built in roto-brush. Also the mask points are just points, they don't have Bézier handles, so they're just straight lines. I would question whether it was worth the time and effort involved writing a script for this. But I don't know your use case.

Comment: @stib Yeah, I agree with you. Result for this one is not that good. 
I'm not an expert at this and am looking for a service that could perform basic rotoscoping which can later be fine-tuned in AE with minimal effort and time. 
I got the result for another couple of videos and they are pretty good - can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4ljtwdn8dnskt6/clearvid_7xfdjfbrjdt.zip?dl=0). It would be great if you could help me with the script to import it as rotobrush result. I believe such a code will be useful for anyone like me.

Comment: Sure, can you be specific about what problems you're having?

Comment: Could you help me get/make a script so that I can import the binary mask co-ordinates into AfterEffects as a roto brush result so that I can modify it further? Thanks for the help.